# how to select items that satisfy 2 conditions in the same column

Tags: mysql

I have a few tables with vehicle information and need to select all models that have variants(versions) fueled by gas and also versions fueled by diesel, ie, exclude all models where all versions are fueled by gas or all versions are fueled by diesel.

My set up is like this (only relevant info):

Table models(primary key model_id)

```
model_id    model
   1         a model
   2         b model
   3         c model
   4         d model
```

Table versions(primary key version_id, model_id and engine_id foreign keys)

```
version_id    model_id     engine_id
   1            1             1
   2            1             2
   3            2             1
   4            2             3
   5            3             2
   6            4             3
   7            3             4
   8            4             5
```

Tables engines (primary key=engine_id)

```
 engine_id      fuel
      1          gas
      2          diesel
      3          gas
      4          diesel
      5          diesel
```

I am looking for a query that would give me models 1 and 4 as they both have gas and diesel versions, as opposed to 2 and 3 that have versions with just one type of fuel.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is called [*Relation Division*](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/), and here is one way to do so:

```
SELECT 
  m.model_id,
  m.model
FROM models         As m
INNER JOIN versions AS v ON m.model_id  = v.model_id
INNER JOIN engines  AS e ON e.engine_id = v.engine_id
WHERE e.fuel IN('gas', 'diesel')
GROUP BY m.model_id, 
         m.model
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT e.fuel) = 2
```

The `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT e.fuel) = 2` will ensure that the selected model have both the two fuels.

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87793/1)

This will give you:

```
| MODEL_ID |   MODEL |
----------------------
|        1 | a model |
|        4 | d model |
```

Comment: i voted up because of the sql fiddle demo (i didn't know about that website, thank you)

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud, it did the job, though I think that the solution from jvilhena is more intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test this, but you can do something like:

```
select model_id, model from models m where 
exists (select 1 from versions v, engines e where m.model_id = v.model_id and e.engine_id = v.engine_id and e.fuel = 'gas') and 
exists (select 1 from versions v, engines e where m.model_id = v.model_id and e.engine_id = v.engine_id and e.fuel = 'diesel')
```

Edit: I tested it with the sql fiddle that Mahmoud Gamal supplied, and it did work :)

Comment: Thanks, jvilhena. I credited Mahmoud as he came up earlier. As I said to him, I believe your approach is more intuitive, but both achieve the desired result.